# Panel with many figures!

Tags: spacing, floats, columns

I would like to count on your help to assemble one panel according to the example:[image]

Comment: Please include any code you've attempted to use so far.

Comment: Welcome! What have you got so far? You may well like to count on other people to do this for you from scratch. You may be fortunate and somebody finds the image attractive and the problem challenging. However, if you would like to count on that, then you would like to be a fool. Even if you provide code, you shouldn't count on somebody answering. Without it, you would more realistically think it would be a wonderful surprise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Since you didn't provide any information about your "panel" I assume, that `beamer` is document class. However, solution can be relatively easy adopted to any document class:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
\multirow{2}*[-1.5ex]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}    \\
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}    \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{my important caption \dots}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

In preamble you need to load the following packages:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code didn't work because of the tabularx packages. In preamble I load the both packages: \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything how you tested my code. If you will provide (in your question) a minimal (not) working example, what you try so far, I will be able to see, what is the problem. This you should do (as you can read in comments on your question) already when you ask for help.

Comment: Sorry, Zarko. I recognize that I was not clear in my doubt. I just play your eating inside the beamer environment. I really need your help. I tested your code compiling on texstudio as follows: \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

\end{document}

Comment: @WendellFialho, now I see that by accident  I have code line `\begin{frame}` twice in my code. Sorry for that. However this error should be easy to find ... If after removing this line your test still not work, please add your test code to your question, that I can see, what is going on.

Comment: Dear Zarko, you have an email where I can send the code and print screen error that is happening? I am not able to attach a picture containing errors.

Comment: @WendellFialho, I give up. I kindly ask you what you should do: let repeat me again:  add your test file to your question by edit it (you have right to this: just click `edit` button and than it is below left of question and than copy file from your edit to question). And please, consider recent version of my answer (from code I remove spurious line, I explain this in comment s before). You can also add screen shot of your error. On this way more people will see your problem and would be able to help you.

Comment: All right, I'll do what you suggested. Thank you for your patience, I am beginner here in the forum and I gradually learning how it works.

Comment: You should edit your question, not my answer! My answer is O.K! If you change code in it, than you will lost track of correct solution.  From your edit attempt I sow, that you try to change`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}` to `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{0.2cm}` This is wrong! `X` is type of column and had not to be changed. Also you not consider last version of my answer.  Frame had to start width `\begin{frame}[fragile]`. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: I made the corrections that you suggested and now it all worked out. Thank you for your help and even more for the patience they had with me (a beginner mere)